# Renaming local files during upload

Tags: javascript, file, file-rename

I'm trying to upload files or multiple files on a web application using AngularJS and C#

Is it entirely possible to rename the files that were successfully uploaded?

Just to avoid confusion, I want to rename the files on the **local drive** to have "_done" on their file name as a marker that they have been uploaded already.

Thanks!

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried that isn't working as expected?

Comment: I'm using HttpPostedFile, but the filename property only has get and cannot be renamed from there.

Comment: `HttpPostedFile` is a server-side concept. You're looking for something client-side.

Comment: Sorry if the answers are vague, I'm only new at this and i'm trying to analyze a made system already.  I tried on js-part to access each file before putting each file into a formdata.

Answer (score 1):

JS does not have edit access to the local-filesystem for security reasons.

Read more here: 
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-copy-and-modify-locally-stored-files-using-JavaScript

The only JS solution would be to use node.js but that requires a server or development-server and would not be possible on a public website.

[Renaming files using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504566/renaming-files-using-node-js)