# Using node.js how to rename all files from a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a folder with multiple files for ex. files with name old.html , old.txt , old.json and i want to rename all these files to new.html , new.txt , new.json.
Is there any method present in node js which i can use here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504566/renaming-files-using-node-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming files using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504566/renaming-files-using-node-js)

Answer (score 7):

This is what you are looking for:

```js
const { join, extname, basename } = require('path');
const { readdirSync, renameSync } = require('fs');

for (const oldFile of readdirSync(pathToOldFolder)) {
    const extension = extname(oldFile);
    const name = basename(oldFile, extension);
    if (name === 'old') {
        renameSync(join(pathToOldFolder, oldFile), join(pathToOldFolder, 'new' + extension));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the FS module?

Use the following to retrieve a list of files

```js
fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});
```

then loop over them to rename the files

```js
fs.rename('oldFile.txt', 'newFile.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Rename complete!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504566/renaming-files-using-node-js), though it may not fulfil your requirement

Put that in a loop over your freshly-read JSON object's keys and values, and you've got a batch renaming script.

like {
file1: old.txt,
file2: old.html,
...
...
...
}

```
fs.readFile('/path/to/countries.json', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var p in obj) {
        fs.rename('/path/to/' + obj[p].split(".")[0] + obj[p].split(".")[1], '/path/to/' + 'new' + obj[p].split(".")[1], function(err) {
            if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
        });
    }
});
```