# How to Rename File In Directory Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having JavaScript file under **menu** directory in the root `menu.js`. I want to rename JavaScript file `menu.js to menuOLD.js` under same directory `onClick`.
I would have googled and found small sample as :

```
function renamefile(){
         const myFile = new File(['hello-world'], 'my-file.txt');
         const myRenamedFile = new File([myFile], 'my-file-final-1-really.txt');
         
         console.log(myRenamedFile);
          
     }
```

I have checked it's output in `Console` and got below output:
[image]

It's working.

But I would need to rename excatly `menu.js` file under `menu` directory.
How should I do this?

Comment: Just for clarification, do you mean that issue is that the old file has to be exactly named `menu.js` or that the new file will be explicitly `menuOLD.js`? If possible, do explain your desired results again.

Comment: @IcyBloom actual file is `menu.js` which has to be renamed as `menuOLD.js`. Renaming will perform if user performs `onClick` event.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to interact with the filesystem in a browser environment (I could be wrong though), but if you are using Node.js, then the `fs` module will let you do that.

Comment: @KeldanChapman kindly show me small demo or reference if possible.

Comment: There is no way to save a file from browser in this way. You need to perform this on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

With Node.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.rename('menu.js', 'menuOLD.js', (err) => { 
  console.log(err);
});
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504566/renaming-files-using-node-js):